# How to best handle orientation changes of Direct3D rendering in Windows Phone Direct3D with XAML app

Tags: xaml, directx, orientation, windows-phone-8

In my WP8 Direct3D with XAML application, when I rotate the device the XAML elements properly rotate with orientation but not the Direct3D view. What is the recommended method to update the Direct3D view after an orientation change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj247544%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) MSDN article (How to detect screen orientation from a Direct3D app for Windows Phone 8). Once you've detected the orientation change, I would recommend using the [World Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206365%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to rotate your Direct3D view. You will also have to re-jigger your projection matrix for this to work correctly.

You could also concatenate the new World transform with your current View and never set the View transform (always Identity) - that might get you better performance on certain platforms.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! I can already detect the device orientation. My question is how to best update the Direct3D view for the new orientation. I've edited my question to be clearer.

Comment: Oh, I see. Edited my answer above.